# Looping into a folder of HTML files and executing a predefined function on each file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, iteration, extract

I am still new to coding. I needed to write a code to iterate through a data folder of many html files and execute a predefined function (Extracting specific tables from HTML document). I used bs4 to parse the html file. The proposed solution below allowed to retrieve the files and extract the tables from each html file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob

def get_soup(html_file_path):  
    f = html_file_path.open()
    return BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

def get_all_tables(soup):
    return soup.find_all("table")

def get_all_html_files(root_path):
    return Path(root_path).glob("**/*.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    html_root = Path("data_file_pathname/")

    soup = get_soup(html_file)

    tables = get_all_tables(soup)
    print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(tables)} tables.")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Path.glob` function from the [`pathlib` standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use).

For example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_soup(html_file_path):  # added argument
    f = html_file_path.open()
    return BeautifulSoup(f, "lxml")

def get_all_tables(soup):
    return soup.find_all("table")

def get_all_html_files(root_path):
    return Path(root_path).glob("**/*.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    html_root = Path("./html_files/")  # This is the folder with the html files

    for html_file in get_all_html_files(html_root):
        soup = get_soup(html_file)
        tables = get_all_tables(soup)
```